# JS: change params format from hash to array

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of JS, where I have `create` action with Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
      table: "#user_groups_table",
      template: '#user_groups_form',
      display: "details",
      idSrc: "id",
      ajax: {
          create: {
              type: 'POST',
              url:  '/strongbolt/user_groups',
          }
      },
      fields: [ {
              name: "name"
          }, {
              name: "description"
          }, {
              type: "checkbox",
              name: "users[].id",
              optionsPair: {
                label: 'name',
                value: 'id'
              }
            }, {
              type: "checkbox",
              name: "roles[].id",
              optionsPair: {
                label: 'name',
                value: 'id'
              }
            }
      ]
    } );

    editor.on( 'preSubmit', function ( e, data, action ) {
      if ( action === 'create' ) {
        data.strongbolt_user_group = {
            "name": data.data[0].name,
            "description": data.data[0].description,
            "user_ids": data.data[0].users,
            "role_ids": data.data[0].roles
        };
        delete data.data;
      }
    } );
```

The last section which starts with `editor.on( 'preSubmit', function ( e, data, action ) {` basically modifies `data` before they are passed to server.

At the moment I get my params in terminal like this:

```
{
  "strongbolt_user_group"=>{
    "name"=>"Some test group",
    "description"=>"Some test description",
    "user_ids"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"3"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"5"}}, 
    "role_ids"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"2"}}
  }
}
```

however I need it to be like this:

```
{
  "strongbolt_user_group"=>{
    "name"=>"Some test group",
    "description"=>"Some test description",
    "user_ids"=>["3", "2", "5"], 
    "role_ids"=>["1", "2"]
  }
}
```

Basically I need `user_ids` and `role_ids` to be array.
**How do I modify this in my JS, please? Thank you!**

Comment: `"user_ids"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"3"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"5"}}` from where u getting this data? Its not JavaScript array or object .Look like PHP

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN It's params passed from JS form input - not PHP. I use Rails and that's why I need to modify my params to array.

Comment: So,=> part coming due to RAILS?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Probably... basically this is is what I see in my terminal. Main thing is I need those `user_ids` and `role_ids` to be array like in my example.

Comment: its better if you do this in rail context and not in JS.Its rails associate array styntax.Can please try to console  the same object  in Browser console? and then share the result

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Doing that on Rails side requires much more code (I have working example already) and data manipulation rather than just changing format before it is passed to server. The accepted answer below worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map the array (or array-like object) of objects to an array of their ids:

```
"user_ids": Array.prototype.map.call(data.data[0].users, function(o) { return o.id; }),
```

If you are certain that `data.data[0].users` is an array, then just use `map` without `call` like:

```
"user_ids": data.data[0].users.map(function(o) { return o.id; }),
```

or even shorter in ES 6's arrow functions:

```
"user_ids": data.data[0].users.map(o => o.id),
```

**Note:** same applies for `role_ids`.